# Mobile Push SDK Opt-in status

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, mobilepush

We are in a process of testing new functionalities for our Mobile Push implementation.

We can set standard and custom attributes via the SDK using **sfmc_setAttributeNamed** but we have some issues with the Opt-in status ([Mobile Push Subscriptions].**OptInStatusID**)

Example :

```
sfmc_setAttributeNamed("OptInStatusID", value: "???")
```

We were able to set it to an empty string but that's it.

How this problem should be approached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html#reserved-words.  You should not be setting this value manually.

Also, if you're having issues with the opted-in status of a device or devices then you should verify the APNS certificate you have registered with the Marketing Cloud servers.  The most common issue (99% of the time) is the wrong certificate being uploaded to your application in the Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

@jclobro, are you validating the result returned from your call to sfmc_setAttributeNamed()?

The method will be returning false in your example, and if you have debug logging enabled in the SDK you'd see:

`[foundation] sfmc_setAttributeNamed key: OptInStatusID, value: ??? failed, name is not valid`

Additionally, if you pass an empty string ( "" ) you'll see:

`[foundation] sfmc_setAttributeNamed key: OptInStatusID, value:  failed, name is not valid`

in the log.